# showing iteration through a DataGridView, updating the display/redraw

Tags: vb.net, forms, datagridview

I have a DataGridView with a single column that currently displays a short list of items. When the user clicks a button to run an update, each row/cell is read and processing begins.

I would like to have the selection indicator move down the rows in the DataGridView as it completes processing of each record. How can I display the iteration of the DataGridView rows while the processing is underway? A redraw of the DataGridView or something.

This is a VB.net windows form, I know how to do this with AJAX I think, but how can I achieve this in a Windows form?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
For each row As DataGridViewRow in myDataGridView.Rows

    'Unselect previous row, then select current row
    myDataGridView.ClearSelection()
    row.Selected = True
    myDataGridView.Refresh()

    'Do processing here...
Next
```

This will select each row but won't scroll down if the current row is out of view. To scroll down automatically you can set the DataGridView `FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex` property.